Is it true that $A[2]\cong \varinjlim_i (A_i[2])$ if $A\cong \varinjlim_{i\in I} A_i$?
Let $I$ be a directed set. Let consider the direct limit in the category of abelian groups. Suppose $A\cong \varinjlim_{i\in I} A_i$. Then, is it true that $A[2]\cong \varinjlim_i (A_i[2])$ ? Here, $[2]$ denotes the 2-part, that is, for abelian group $M$, $M[2]=\{x\in M\mid 2x=0\}$
Do you think does this hold in general ?
example 1. $\varinjlim_{i\in \Bbb{N}} \frac{1}{n}\Bbb{Z}\cong \Bbb{Q}$ and $\varinjlim_{i\in \Bbb{N}}(\dfrac{1}{n}\Bbb{Z})[2]\cong 0$ indeed holds.
But I don't have confident on counter examples.
Thank you for very much for your help.

Your example is not a direct limit but an inverse limit.

Also, $(\mathbb{Z}/i\mathbb{Z})[2] = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is only valid when $i$ is even.

The maps of your limit on 2 torsion and all equal to $0$, so the limit is trivial as expected. Just think of the map $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})[2] \to (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[2]$.

And even for powers of $2$, you are completely neglecting what the transition maps are: the canonical reduction $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ induces the zero map $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})[2]\to (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[2]\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

This is true if the colimit is filtered. Then $M[2] = \textrm{ker}(M \stackrel{2}{\to} M )$ is the kernel of a canonical map, and kernels commute with filtered colimits for abelian groups.
In other words:
$$ \varinjlim M_i[2] = \varinjlim \textrm{ker}( M_i \stackrel{2}{\to } M_i) = \textrm{ker}( \varinjlim (M_i \stackrel{2}{\to } M_i)) =  \textrm{ker}( M \stackrel{2}{\to } M) = M[2] $$
All equalities here are intended to be isomorphisms.

Isn't $\varinjlim \textrm{ker}( M_i \stackrel{2}{\to } M_i) \cong \textrm{coker}( \varinjlim (M_i \stackrel{2}{\to } M_i))$ from universal property of direct limit ?

No! Ker is a colimit, Coker is a limit. Unfortunately, no commutation rule holds in general between limits and colimits (think about them as product and sum, you do not have $(a+b)(c+d)=ab+cd$). However, when you have filtered colimits, it does commute with finite limits in cerain categories. See the discussion on filtered colimits on nLab for example

Changing inverse limit in linked page (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2013401/category-theory-limits-commute-with-kernels/2013415#comment10566972_2013415) into direct limit, I think formula at first my comment is indeed true and I cannot find the reason why your second '=' holds.

Sorry, I made a typo in the above comment. Kernel is a limit and cokernel is a colimit. So you expect (as in the linked page) kernel to commute with limit, but not with colimit in general (except for the filtered case). Your formula cannot be right: if the diagram is made up of a single object, you would be saying that the kernel and cokernel of the map coincide. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/filtered+colimit for the discussion about filtered colimit commuting with finite limits (in paritucalr kernels) of abelian groups, that justify my second passage.

Revisiting the universality diagram again, I realized that it indeed does not commute. Thanks to this, my research seems to be progressing. Thank you very much.

I think this should always be true. We have a natural map $\lim\limits_{\rightarrow}(A_i[2])\rightarrow(\lim\limits_{\rightarrow}A_i)[2]$ induced by the inclusions $A_i[2]\hookrightarrow A_i$. We can verify that this map is injective by the construction of direct limits. Now we check that it is surjective.
Consider an 2-torsion element $x$ in $\lim\limits_{\rightarrow}A_i$ represent by $a_i\in A_i$. Since $2a_i=0\in\lim\limits_{\rightarrow}A_i$, we know there exists an index $j\geq i$ such that $f_{ij}(2a_i)=0$ in $A_j$ where $f_{ij}:A_i\rightarrow A_j$ is the map in the direct system. Thus $f_{ij}(a_i)\in A_j[2]$, and hence the element represented by $f_{ij}(a_i)$ in $\lim\limits_{\rightarrow}(A_i[2])$ maps to $x$ under that natural map. So we have checked that the natural map at the beggining is an isomorphism.

I'm not quite familiar with the terminology, but I guess "directed" might be a synonym of "filtered". So this answer coincides with Andrea Marino's above.
